# Shiny : showing one message for all errors

Tags: r, shiny

I have an application in R's Shiny. I would like to handle messages so that users do not see what error occurred. I know that via

```
 tags$style(type="text/css",
                        ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
                        ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
            ),
```

I can disable error messages entirely, but I would like to show users one message like

> An error occurred. Please contact the admin.

whenever message of whatever type occurs (and still keep the original error message in the log). Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `options(shiny.sanitize.errors = TRUE)` somewhere in your app. All error messages will then be replaced with the generic error message:

**Error**: An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.

If you do want a particular error to pass through unsanitised, you can use `base::stop(shiny::safeError(e))` instead of just `base::stop(e)`, where `e` is an error string or object with class 'error'.

Reference: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/sanitize-errors.html

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question.  I only thought about it for one minute so I'm sure there are better, cleaner solutions that use R code, but here's a CSS solution since you used CSS in the question

Basically, since I saw that you used a `:before`, it made me realize that you can just change the text of that pseudoelement.

```
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$style(type="text/css",
               ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
               ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: visible; content: 'An error occurred. Please contact the admin.'; }"
    ),
    textOutput("text")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$text <- renderText({
      stop("lalala")
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: Thank You for Your solution - the example works nicely on its own. However, when I included the code into my app, it does not work. If the error is caused by fact that app is trying to pull out data but goes none (and tries to perform calculations on them), it just print "Error: " and not the desired message.

Comment: Is it possible to use a link (like "a href" in html) in the content?

Comment: Not using this solution. This CSS solution relies on the CSS content property, which can only have plain text, not links.