# Can I print run error on shiny UI with a single function?

Tags: r, error-handling, shiny

I have a shiny app that has dozens of procedures.From time to time there is an error that halts the program.I need to let the user see that the app halts ( he doesn't see the console).I can use `try-catch` but It will be hard and not elegant to do it for every single procedure.Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887205/shiny-showing-one-message-for-all-errors

Comment: The solution in the link above is not working for me.

Comment: Why doesnt the link work for you? You want an event specific error message?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that doesn't use CSS.

Comment: You can have a look at this elegant error handling : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780692/change-error-message-with-shiny-app